# Passport.js successful authentication not calling at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

Here is My code :

```
passport.use(new localStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({
            username: username
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!user) {
                console.log("Unknown User");
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: "Unknown User"
                })
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                console.log("Incorrect password.", password);
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Incorrect password.'
                });
            }

            console.log("User Is detected");
            return done(null, user, {
                message: "User Is detected"

            })

        });
    }
));


router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true,
        successFlash: 'Welcome!'
    }),
    function(req, res) { // this function not called
        console.log(req)
    });
```

everything works perfectly , but success function not calling and i want to have this message : `"welcome"+req.body.username` after logged in .

Any Advice ? thx

Comment: Are you getting any of the console.log from LocalStrategy?

Comment: @HirenS. yes, all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of `passport.authenticate()`](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate):

> the redirect options override the default behavior

In your example, because you set the `successRedirect` option, the next function in the middleware chain will not be invoked upon successful authentication.

If you want to your function to be invoked before redirecting to `'/'`, then you should:

```
router.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true
    }),
    function(req, res) {
        // This should show up in your logs:
        console.log('Welcome ' + req.body.username);

        // You can also use a flash to consume after redirect:
        // (provided that you use connect-flash in your app)
        req.flash('info', 'Welcome ' + req.body.username);

        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

Comment: you are a life saver :)